# Java Persistence API Factory method error

Tags: jpa

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Employee
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at Emp.Employee_Details.main(Employee_Details.java:74)
```

Comment: Please provide related code.

Comment: This must be "StackOverflow - the site where you dump your exception and provide no context and expect mind reading to fix your problem"

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you forgot add persistence provider in persistence.xml. If you use hibernate, it must be something like this:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```